# Why is I = $\partial Q / \partial t$ and not $I=-\partial Q / \partial t$?

Tags: electric-current, charge, conservation-laws, conventions

I was playing around the Maxwell equations and I came across this:

$$\nabla\cdot J =-\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$$

$$\iiint_V{\nabla\cdot J \space \partial V} = \iint_A{J\cdot\partial A}$$

$$-\iiint_V{ \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t} \cdot\partial V}=\iint_A{J\cdot\partial A}=I$$

$$I=-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\iiint_V{\rho}\cdot\partial V$$

$$I=-\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}$$

However, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_current), the definition is this:

[image: Wikipedia]

So how come every definition I come across doesn't contain the negative sign? Physically if a current is flowing in the positive direction, shouldn't the charge by decreasing at that point as it becomes more negative?

Comment: *. . . . I came across this . . . .* please give details of where you found these equations as whether or not you have a minus sign depends on the convention being used.

Comment: I used the Ampere's law in Maxwell's equations $\nabla\times B = \mu_0 J + \mu_0\epsilon_0 \partial E / \partial t$. I wasn't aware of any other version of this equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you're using the divergence theorem, surface $A$ is oriented from the inside to the outside, making it a charge loss for the system: current is positive when charges leave the system.

On the other hand, in electricity, the usual $i=dq/dt$ relies on the opposite norm: $q$ rises when the current enters the system (think capacitor).

Comment: Alright I think I understand, I realized that the two equation are describing different scenarios